# Resizing super view depending on the content of the subview in iOS 8

Tags: autolayout, ios8, uicontainerview

In iOS 8, resizing the superview depending on the subview's content doesn't seem to work.

I have a container view with no height constraint which embeds a view controller with the height of the content defined (two views with background colours green and orange, respectively).

In iOS 7 it works (as usual) but not in iOS 8, as depicted below. I'm using Xcode 6 and have defined all constraints in the storyboard.

Is this a bug?

[image: iOS 8: the container view has no height (and hence nothing is shown).]
[image: iOS 7: The height of the container view has been determined w.r.t. the embedded view.]